# 404 error while updating Product inventory by rest API Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api, magento2.3.1, cataloginventory

I am trying to integrate Magento 2.3.1 with Linnworks,
All the api calls are working fine expect the CatalogInventory.

When we try to update the product inventory using rest

**PUT https://sitename.com/rest/default/V1/products/:productSku/stockItems/:itemId**

its showing **404: Not Found**

Anyone please help me on this..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Whick method you have used ? Get?

Comment: @aravind PUT method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have fixed a similar issue by adding the following in .htaccess file inside public_html

```
<Limit GET POST PUT OPTIONS>
Require all granted
</Limit>
<LimitExcept GET POST PUT OPTIONS>
Require all denied
</LimitExcept>
```

Please make sure the Apache Module mod_headers is enabled  [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html)

Comment: Thanks.. Issue resolved..

Comment: wow that done the trick!!